# How can I reverse the byte order of an int?

Tags: c#, actionscript, arrays

I am having a hard time converting this ActionScript code to C#.  I don't understand how I can mimic what ByteArray() is doing in C#. If anyone could help me recreate this functionality I would really appreciate it.

ActionScript (`seed` is a uint.):

```
//Start by reversing the byte order of the seed
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
ba.writeInt(seed);
ba.position = 0;
ba.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
seed = ba.readInt();
```

Comment: See also: [How to get little endian data from big endian](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8241060/580951)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `BitConverter.GetBytes(UInt32)` to get your `byte[]`, then call `Array.Reverse` on the array, then use `BitConverter.ToUInt32(byte[])` to get your int back out.

**Edit**

Here's a more efficient and cryptic way to do it:

```
public static UInt32 ReverseBytes(UInt32 value)
{
     return (value & 0x000000FFU) << 24 | (value & 0x0000FF00U) << 8 |
         (value & 0x00FF0000U) >> 8 | (value & 0xFF000000U) >> 24;
}
```

This is what you need to know to understand what's happening here:

1. A UInt32 is 4 bytes.
2. In hex, two characters represent one byte. 179 in decimal == B3 in hex == 10110011 in binary.
3. A bitwise and (`&`) preserves the bits that are set in **both** inputs: `1011 0011 & 1111 0000 = 1011 0000`; in hex: `B3 & F0 = B0`.
4. A bitwise or (`|`) preserves the bits that are set in **either** input: `1111 0000 | 0000 1111 = 1111 1111`; in hex, `F0 | 0F = FF`.
5. The bitwise shift operators (`<<` and `>>`) move the bits left or right in a value. So `0011 1100 << 2 = 1111 0000`, and `1100 0011 << 4 = 0011 0000`.

So `value & 0x000000FFU` returns a UInt32 with all but the 4th byte set to 0. Then `<< 24` moves that 4th byte to the left 24 places, making it the 1st byte. Then  `(value & 0x0000FF00U) << 8` zeros out everything but the 3rd byte and shifts it left so it is the second byte. And so on. The four `(x & y) << z` create four UInt32s where each of the bytes have been moved to the place they will be in the reversed value. Finally, the `|` combines those UIntt32s bytes back together into a single value.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast response.

Comment: May you add a section to explain how _the cryptic way_ works?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin, I've added an explanation.

Comment: It's some time since this was asked, but the IPAddress class has static Methods to convert between host and network byte orders:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder(v=vs.110).aspx