# Convert a ushort value into two byte values in C#

Tags: c#, byte, boolean-logic, ushort

How do I split a ushort into two byte variables in C#?

I tried the following (package.FrameID is ushort):

When I try to calculate this with paper&pencil I get the right result. Also, if FrameID is larger than a byte (so the second byte isn't zero), it works.

```
array[0] = (byte)(0x0000000011111111 & package.FrameID);
array[1] = (byte)(package.FrameID >> 8);
```

In my case package.FrameID is 56 and the result in array[0] is 16 instead of 56.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`0x0000000011111111` is not a binary number, it's a hex number. You need to use `0x0ff` instead.

However, since the result is a byte and casting to a byte will discard the upper bits anyway, you don't actually need to `and` the result. You can just do this:

```
array[0] = (byte)package.FrameID;
array[1] = (byte)(package.FrameID >> 8);
```

(That's assuming that you are not using `checked` code. If you are, then casting a value greater than 255 to a `byte` will cause an exception. You will know if you are using `checked` code.)

Comment: `0x0f` is 1 byte, if we perform a `bit and` operation on it and the `ushort`, the return value is only the lower-nibble of the lower byte, I think it's `0x00ff`.

Comment: You could also use `0x0000000011111111` if you wanted to use the binary number (notice leading 0b instead of 0x)

Answer (score 21):

Use [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx)

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(package.FrameID);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But any Idea whats the problem with my solution?

Comment: @user2071938 `0x0000000011111111` is a 8-byte **hex** number. They are not bits as you think. it should be `0x00ff`

Comment: @user2071938 1 hex digit stands for 4 bits, so 1 byte will correspond to 2 hex digits.

Comment: This is the best solution. Regarding the constant `0x0000000011111111`, it _seems_ to be an 8-byte number (16 hex digits), but since the leading 8 hex digits are all zero, it is interpreted as a 4-byte number. And since the first non-zero digit (`1`) is between `1` and `7`, not between `8` and `f`, this is an `int`, not a `uint`. You can try `var a = 0x11223344;` (`int`), `var b = 0x81223344;` (`uint`), `var c = 0x112233448899aabb;` (`long`), `var d = 0x812233448899aabb;` (`ulong`).

Comment: old question, but BitConverter is risky since it depends on the endianness of the system see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241060/how-to-get-little-endian-data-from-big-endian-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-toin