# Transform bytes to structure and back

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

My goal is to transform array of bytes to c# structure and back. Assume I receive the following data from an external source:

```
byte[] bytes = {
    0x10, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00
};
```

I know that first two bytes mean "ushort" value, next 4 bytes mean "uint". Bytes come in "high-endian" order. For keeping the decoded result I declare the following structure:

```
struct Envelop
{
    public ushort Value1;
    public uint Value2;
}
```

Now I'd like to create an instance of "Envelop" and fill it in according to the data. Is there any standard functionality for that?

```
Envelop data = SomeStandardFunctionality<Envelop>(bytes);

Console.WriteLine(data.Value1); // 16
Console.WriteLine(data.Value2); // 257
```

I also need possibility to transform this structure back to array which should look exactly at the initial one. I believe that both tasks are parts of the same functionality in c#.

Comment: This question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587611/convert-a-ushort-value-into-two-byte-values-in-c-sharp

Comment: Not really: your existing data is not padded correctly. You can read each value individually using `BitConverter` or `Unsafe.As`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest, you can get without going into very unsafe territory is, reading the values separately using `BinaryPrimitives`.

```
var data = new Envelop
{
    Value1 = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16LittleEndian(bytes),
    Value2 = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt32LittleEndian(bytes[2..])
};

Console.WriteLine(data.Value1); // LittleEndian: 16, BigEndian: 4096
Console.WriteLine(data.Value2); // LittleEndian: 65537, BigEndian 16777472
```

If you want to directly copy the memory, you can do this, but this is quite unsafe, because your results will depend on the endianess of the system.

```
var data = new Envelop();
var ptr = new IntPtr(&data);
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);

Console.WriteLine(data.Value1); // 16
Console.WriteLine(data.Value2); // 65537

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Envelop
{
    public ushort Value1;
    public uint Value2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You are right regarding endians: better to handle them explicitly.

Comment: The direct copy version doesn't need the complex `Marshal` code - just `MemoryMarshal.AsRef<Envelop>(bytes)` (all the same endianness warnings still apply, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MemoryMarshal.AsRef` if the endianess of the system running the code is the same as the one of the data:

```
byte[] bytes = {
    0x10, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00
};

Envelop data = MemoryMarshal.AsRef<Envelop>(bytes);

Console.WriteLine(data.Value1);
Console.WriteLine(data.Value2);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct Envelop
{
    public ushort Value1;
    public uint Value2;
}
```