# BlockCopy alternative that allows me to choose endianness

Tags: c#, endianness

Say I have an array of bytes:

```
byte[] input = { 0xFF, 0xFc, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

You can use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy bytes from one array to another, regardless of type.  So, I can do this:

```
uint[] output = new uint[1];
Buffer.BlockCopy(input , 0, output, 0, input.Length);
```

This will copy the bytes from input to output, converting them from an array of bytes to an array of uints along the way.

The problem is that `BlockCopy` interprets the bytes with little endianness.  I need a copy that uses big endianness.  So rather than getting a uint value of 4294705152 (0xFFFC0000), like I need, I get the value 64767 (0x0000FCFF).  Note that this is a bare-bones example, I cannot easily reverse the order of the bytes in my actual application.

Is there anything with the convenience and speed of `BlockCopy` that includes the ability to set the endianness I need?

Comment: It is important to note that BlockCopy endianness is system dependent, it does not necessarily interpret the bytes as little endian,  this is generally on Windows based systems.  (form Microsoft docs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netframework-4.8 )  : "... which byte of array element -49 is accessed first depends on the endianness of the computer that is executing your application..." .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic seems to be covered here:

[How to get little endian data from big endian in c# using bitConverter.ToInt32 method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241060/how-to-get-little-endian-data-from-big-endian-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-toin)

However the conversion has to be iterated on the entire input array.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was some super-secret hacker method of doing it without having to use the BitConverter.  There's a significant loss of speed and I have lots of data that would need to be handled.