# How to send big endian to network stream using c#

Tags: c#, tcp, endianness

I try to transfer a filedata with sockets via a sslStream. It seems that I must send the file data length before the data. The problem is that the code

```
Byte [] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileData.Length)
```

Returns in little endian but internet protocols are using big endian.

How I can convert this to big endian and write it to stream;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get little endian data from big endian in c# using bitConverter.ToInt32 method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241060/how-to-get-little-endian-data-from-big-endian-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-toin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to send just one `int` value. The order of the bytes should be reversed before transmitting:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileData.Length);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
     Array.Reverse(bytes);
```

Check [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more information about `BitConverted`.

You could also convert it using [`HostToNetworkOrder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
int reversed = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(fileData.Length);
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(reversed);
```

To send these bytes use the [`Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```