# c# netcore2.0 int to bytes conversion with endianess support

Tags: c#, .net-core, endianness

I am developing an Envelope encryption library where envelope structure is combination of byte arrays.

```
keyAlias length , keyAlias , IVBytes, cipherBytes = 
[int][keyAlias][IV][cipherBytes]
```

As I am storing first 4 bytes of int to retrieve the length of keyAlias from envelope bytes, looking for correct handling of int to bytes and back to int.

Assumptions : I have decide to always store int bytes in Little-Endian format in envelope bytes.

Does below method for int to bytes correct. I have no way to test it as not having access to Big-Endian machine.

```
[Fact]
public void IntToByteConverion_ShouldConvertBack2()
{
    var intBytes = 2.ToLittleEndianBytes();

    //Store intBytes to Database or AWS S3
    // Retrive back the bytearray and convert to int32.

    int intValue = intBytes.FromLittleEndianBytes();

    Assert.Equal(2, intValue);
}

public static byte[] ToLittleEndianBytes(this int value)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    else
    {
        var bigEndianBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        Array.Reverse(bigEndianBytes);// Converted to LittleEndian
        return bigEndianBytes;
    }
}

public static Int32 FromLittleEndianBytes(this byte[] littleEndianBytes)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(littleEndianBytes, 0);
    else
    {
        Array.Reverse(littleEndianBytes);// Converted to big endian as machine CPU is big endian
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(littleEndianBytes, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get little endian data from big endian in c# using bitConverter.ToInt32 method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241060/how-to-get-little-endian-data-from-big-endian-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-toin)

Comment: In  the question I have stated I encode myint with LittleEndian and transmit or store it in db as bytes. If you refer article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.8   It says common convention is to send bytes in Big Endian way over the network. As I am not following this convention, just want to confirm this will not result in any bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done works. To test it you can replace:

```
if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
```

with:

```
if (false/*BitConverter.IsLittleEndian*/)
```

and check with the debugger if the bytes are actually reversed. If so (which it is) then it works, because the difference between Little-Endian and Big-Endian is the byte order.

Just one comment on your code (this is probably more in the scope of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)):

Using:

```
Array.Reverse(littleEndianBytes);
```

in method:

```
Int32 FromLittleEndianBytes(this byte[] littleEndianBytes)
```

is not the best practice since you are reversing the byte array sent to the method. The user of the method may not expect it and be confused.